# "if" statement based on command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I understand from Python's documentation that I can check conditions with the format:

```
if x < 0:
else:
    print('Else code')
```

I want to run a command and check whether that command is successful, but I get a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" error.  Help!

My format is roughly:

```
if myCommand(parameters):
    print("It worked")
else:
    print("It failed")
    if mySecondCommand(parameters):
        print("2nd command worked")
    else:
        print("2nd command failed")
```

And here's my actual code using the Netmiko library:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
if net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip='11.22.33.44', username='domain.login', password='DomainPassword'):
    print("Domain login succeeded.")
else:
    print("Domain login failed.")
    if net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip='11.22.33.44', username='StandardUsername', password='StandardPassword'):
        print("Standard login worked")
    else:
        print("Standard login failed")
```

The output I get is:

```
if net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip='11.22.33.444', username='domain.login', password='DomainPassword'):
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You can't put a variable assignment inside an `if` condition. Did you mean to compare `net_connect == ConnectHandler` instead?

Comment: In Python assignment is a statement only and can't be used as an expression. Are you trying to check if they're equal or do the assignment and check for a truthy value?

Comment: Without digging into the NetMiko documentation, I would assume that either `ConnectHandler` will raise an exception to catch if the connection fails, or you need to check some attribute of the return value. In either case, it certainly isn't returning a boolean value indicating whether the connection failed or not.

Comment: @UnholySheep Oh, possibly.  Essentially, if I run the "net_connect = blah blah" command in the Python shell, it'll successfully login and I can run more commands.  Basically I'm trying to check whether running the command would return an "Authentication failed" error or not.

Comment: @puterguy01 In that command you mentioned, what will happen if you don't login successfully?

Comment: @KyrSt I get:  

paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoAuthenticationException: Authentication failure: unable to connect cisco_ios 11.22.33.44:22
Authentication failed.

Comment: @puterguy01 So, essentially what you need to do "catch" that Exception. An "if statement" is not able to help you. I am writing an answer to explain in detail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the comments provided to this question, it seems that what you essentially need is how to know if the connection failed. Since a failed connection raises an exception, if-statements are not enough / needed to achieve what you want. Instead, you would like to do this:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
try:
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip='11.22.33.44', username='domain.login', password='DomainPassword')
    print("Domain login succeeded.")
except:
    print("Domain login failed.")

    try:
        net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip='11.22.33.44',username='StandardUsername', password='StandardPassword')
        print("Standard login worked")
    except:
        print("Standard login failed")
```

If you have not come across "try-except" statements in Python, I suggest you looked them up.

Comment: Ah, yup, this is exactly what I needed.  I'm a noob - I had no idea there was a difference between if-else statements and try-except statements.  Looks like I need to do lots more studying.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your original snippet will raise a syntax error, you can't run this (*thanks to* [*KyrST*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6942918/kyrst)):

```
if x < 0:
else:
    print('Else code')
```

you'd want this:

```
if not x < 0:
    print("Not X < 0 code")
```

The issue that caused the error lies here:

```
if net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip='11.22.33.44', username='domain.login', password='DomainPassword'):
```

In Python, you cannot assign a value inside a condition, and even if you did, what would you compare it to?
what you should do is instead of the above:

```
net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip='11.22.33.44', username='domain.login', password='DomainPassword'):
if net_connect == some_check_here:
```

some_check_here being some value you can use to compare if something goes wrong, I'm not sure how netmiko handles errors, my guess is that you'll have to catch exceptions.

Comment: actually, the first code snippet (that was given by the OP) will give a syntax error. There is no statement in the "then" clause. I think it should also be pinpointed

Comment: Will do, even if it did work it would not be very idiomatic or logical.

Comment: This is the closest thing to a good answer so far, as it doesn't assume that `net_connect` is a pre-existing value to compare to the return value of `ConnectHandler`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new but I try to make as much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a variable within an `if` statement (not allowed in Python), instead of checking for equality.

Try:

```
 if net_connect == ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip='11.22.33.44', username='domain.login', password='DomainPassword'):
    ...
```

and notice the use of `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Python can't have variable assignment inside an if statement - it can't be used as an expression.

with the `=` operator, you're attempting to *assign* the net_connect variable, rather than compare it.

the `==` operator is the correct operator for comparison, so:

`if net_connect == ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip='11.22.33.44', username='domain.login', password='DomainPassword'):` is correct, as you're comparing the two.

Your original, `if net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip='11.22.33.444', username='domain.login', password='DomainPassword'):`, the ConnectHandler to net_connect.